# How to consume message from a topic in Prometheus

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus

I am working on Kafka --> Prometheus --> Grafana pipeline. I have java application which send message inside a kafka topic. But in prometheus it shows only the message count of topic. I am running an instance of JMX Exporter when I run Kafka.

```
    export JMX_YAML=/home/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/prometheus/kafka-0-8-2.yml
    export JMX_JAR=/home/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.6.jar
    export KAFKA_OPTS="$KAFKA_OPTS -javaagent:$JMX_JAR=7076:$JMX_YAML"
    bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

But I need to read the topic data in prometheus. Is there any direct Kafka to Prometheus importer? 
I have heard about "Kafka Connect framework"? How to configure it inside prometheus?

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus doesn't run Kafka Connect; you would have to configure that separately.

Also, Prometheus is pulled based, so you at the very least would have to use PushGateway, assuming a Kafka Connector did exist.

If you just want to ultimately display data in Grafana, there are existing connectors for Elasticsearch, Influx, Cassandra, and most JDBC databases

Telegraf or Logstash could be used as alternatives to Kafka Connect, as well, or you can write your own consumer.